# Generate URL from database results

Tags: php, html

I am busy writing a function for our internal wiki where users can download pdf books from the wiki. Essentially all they need is a custom url eg `http://10.32.6.151/index.php?title=Category:Encashments&action=pdfbook` which will compile the book and make it available for them.

To make everyone's lives easier i wanted to simplify the process by creating a dropdown list where they can select the book they want and then download it by clicking a link

here is my form code `pdfbook.php`

```
<?php

$servername = "XXXXXXXX";
$username = "wikidb";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXXXX";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_title FROM wiki_category";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form action='generateurl.php' name='pdfbook' id='pdfbook' method='post'>";
echo "<select name='id'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    unset($id, $name);
    $id = $row['cat_id'];
    $name = $row['cat_title'];
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";


?>
```

and here is my code for generateurl.php

```
<?php
$catname = $_POST[$id];
?>

<html>
<head>
<body>
<a class="button" type="button" href="http://10.32.6.151/index.php?title=Category:<?php echo $catname?>&action=pdfbook">Click here to Download the PDF Book</a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

When i click the submit button it takes me through to the page with the URL however the url does not contain the category name. So it is not pulling the cat name or id from the previous page.

Comment: Please provide more information - what is not working. Is your form displaying as expected. Do you get the page with the URL. Is the URL link working?

Comment: @MortimerCat the page with the url is being displayed. however the link it generates is not working. so its not pulling the $id from the previous page and inserting it into the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not picking up the POST correctly. Should be....

```
$catname = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, i also just figured it out. Thats what happens when you dont focus!

Answer (score 1):

In generateurl.php page, you should retrieve POST param like this :
$var = $_POST['varName'];

This should give you the "id" passed from previous page. Also, displaying this "id" in the download URL will make download URL like this :
http://10.32.6.151/index.php?title=Category:9662&action=pdfbook
I mean, a numeric value will be displayed. If you want to display name of the category this you need to fetch that from category table and display that instead of primary key i.e. id of the table.